# UISearchBar seems to be returning right count, but not the right rows

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to implement a search function in my app. For now, I'm just trying to search by the State value my JSON, though I'd like to eventually include Category as well. There are 9 rows total, the first 7 are State=AZ and the last 2 are State=CA. When I search for "KK" the table is empty, which makes sense. But when I search for "CA" I get two rows like I expect, but they are the first two rows in the JSON, which are both AZ, not the two CA rows it should be.

I suspect my issue is somewhere in my `filterContentForSearchText` function, but since I'm not sure exactly which code you need, here is the ViewController (the function I think is the issue is down near the end):

```
import UIKit
import os.log
import Foundation

class BonusListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var bonuses = [JsonFile.JsonBonuses]()
    var filteredBonuses = [JsonFile.JsonBonuses]()
    var detailViewController: BonusDetailViewController? = nil

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // MARK: Search Support
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Enter two letter state to filter"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true

        // MARK: Settings Data Struct
        struct Constants {
            struct RiderData {
                let riderNumToH = "riderNumToH"
                let pillionNumToH = "pillionNumToH"
            }
            struct RallyData {
                let emailDestinationToH = "emailDestinationToH"
            }
        }
        //MARK: Load the bonuses
        loadBonuses { [weak self] bonuses in
            self?.bonuses = bonuses ?? []
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            print("loadBonuses called")
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Table View Configuration
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if isFiltering() {
            print("Showing \(filteredBonuses.count) Filtered Results")
            return filteredBonuses.count
        }

        print("Found \(bonuses.count) rows in section.")
        return bonuses.count
    }

    /* Disabling the swipe function until I code it to actually do something
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
    {
        let clearAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Clear Data") { (contextAction: UIContextualAction, sourceView: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in
            print("Clear Action Tapped")
            completionHandler(true)
        }

        clearAction.backgroundColor = .blue
        let swipeConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [clearAction])
        return swipeConfig
    }
    */

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "BonusListViewCell"
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? BonusListViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of BonusListViewCell.")
        }
        let bonus = bonuses[indexPath.row]
        let bonusSet: JsonFile.JsonBonuses
        if isFiltering() {
            bonusSet = filteredBonuses[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            bonusSet = bonus
        }

        let urlString = "http://tourofhonor.com/appimages/"+(bonus.imageName)
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        cell.primaryImage.downloadedFrom(url: url!)
        cell.nameLabel.text = bonus.name.capitalized
        cell.bonusCodeLabel.text = bonus.bonusCode.localizedUppercase
        cell.categoryLabel.text = bonus.category
        cell.valueLabel.text = "\(bonus.value)"
        cell.cityLabel.text = "\(bonus.city.capitalized),"
        cell.stateLabel.text = bonus.state.localizedUppercase

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: Functions
    // MARK: - Fetch JSON from ToH webserver

    func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping ([JsonFile.JsonBonuses]?) -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil, let data = data {
                do {
                    let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFile.self, from: data)
                    completed(posts.bonuses)
                } catch {
                    print("JSON Download Failed")
                }
            } else {
                print("downloadJSON completed")
                completed(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func saveBonuses(_ bonuses: [JsonFile.JsonBonuses], to url: URL) {
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
        do {
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(bonuses)
            try data.write(to: url)
            print("saveBonuses successful")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving bonuses to file:", error)
        }
    }

    func loadBonusesFromFile(_ url: URL) -> [JsonFile.JsonBonuses]? {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let bonuses = try JSONDecoder().decode([JsonFile.JsonBonuses].self, from: data)
            print("loadBonusesFromFile successful")
            return bonuses
        } catch {
            print("Error loading bonuses from file:", error)
            return nil
        }
    }

    func loadBonuses(completion: @escaping ([JsonFile.JsonBonuses]?) -> Void) {
        let localBonusesURL = try! FileManager.default
            .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appendingPathComponent("Bonuses.json")
        downloadJSON { bonuses in
            if let bonuses = bonuses {
                completion(bonuses)
                self.saveBonuses(bonuses, to: localBonusesURL)
            } else {
                completion(self.loadBonusesFromFile(localBonusesURL))
            }
        }
    }

    func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
        // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredBonuses = bonuses.filter({( bonus: JsonFile.JsonBonuses) -> Bool in
            return bonus.state.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func isFiltering() -> Bool {
        return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? BonusDetailViewController {
            destination.bonus = bonuses[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
    }
}

extension BonusListViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    // MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

and here is the JsonFile.swift:

```
import Foundation

struct JsonFile: Codable {
    struct Meta: Codable {
        let fileName: String
        let version: String
    }
    struct JsonBonuses: Codable {
        let bonusCode: String
        let category: String
        let name: String
        let value: Int
        let city: String
        let state: String
        let flavor: String
        let imageName: String
    }
    let meta: Meta
    let bonuses: [JsonBonuses]
}
```

EDIT: The JSON itself can be found at http://www.tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json

Also, on the line that says `let bonusSet: JsonFile.JsonBonuses` (under the cellForRowAt), I'm getting a warning that says "Immutable value `bonusSet` was never used; consider removing it" even though I use it in the very next line.

Comment: can you post your json Responce?

Comment: You do set it in the next line but you never read it. A local that is initialized without being read is pointless.

Comment: @RahulGUsai I edited my question to include the link to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the issue is in your cellForRow method, you are supposed to assignv alues with bonusSet and not bonus. as you are initializing the value from bonus dara structure which should be from bonusSet.

Try changing cellForRow as:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "BonusListViewCell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? BonusListViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of BonusListViewCell.")
    }
    let bonus = bonuses[indexPath.row]
    let bonusSet: JsonFile.JsonBonuses
    if isFiltering() {
        bonusSet = filteredBonuses[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        bonusSet = bonus
    }

    //CHANGE IS REQUIRED HERE: REPLACE THE bonus WITH bonusSet :
    let urlString = "http://tourofhonor.com/appimages/"+(bonusSet.imageName)
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    cell.primaryImage.downloadedFrom(url: url!)
    cell.nameLabel.text = bonusSet.name.capitalized
    cell.bonusCodeLabel.text = bonusSet.bonusCode.localizedUppercase
    cell.categoryLabel.text = bonusSet.category
    cell.valueLabel.text = "\(bonusSet.value)"
    cell.cityLabel.text = "\(bonusSet.city.capitalized),"
    cell.stateLabel.text = bonusSet.state.localizedUppercase

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your cell for row index path

search result you are getting from the filterContentForSearchText you are storing in filteredBonuses but in cellForRowAt you are still setting all your values from 
bouns variable

> bonus = bonuses[indexPath.row]

```
if isFiltering() {
        bonusSet = filteredBonuses[indexPath.row] //even though you are creating bonusSet you are not using it while setting cell values below so use that bonusSet
    } else {
        bonusSet = bonus
    }


//Like this
let urlString = "http://tourofhonor.com/appimages/"+(bonusSet.imageName)
let url = URL(string: urlString)
cell.primaryImage.downloadedFrom(url: url!)
cell.nameLabel.text = bonus.name.capitalized
cell.bonusCodeLabel.text = bonusSet.bonusCode.localizedUppercase
cell.categoryLabel.text = bonusSet.category
cell.valueLabel.text = "\(bonusSet.value)"
cell.cityLabel.text = "\(bonusSet.city.capitalized),"
cell.stateLabel.text = bonusSet.state.localizedUppercase
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is useless:

```
    let bonusSet: JsonFile.JsonBonuses
    if isFiltering() {
        bonusSet = filteredBonuses[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        bonusSet = bonus
    }
```

You create a local variable `bonusSet` whose value depends on whether you are filtering; but, as the compiler rightly observes, nothing you do afterwards uses it. Your code thus behaves exactly the same way regardless of whether you are filtering.